# Html.fromHtml obsoleto para Android N+

Tags: java, html, android, deprecated

No Android 7.0 (API level 24) o método estático `fromHtml()` da classe pública [**Html**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) se tornou obsoleto não sei por qual motivo, se souberem me fale. Veja um exemplo de como era usado:

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h3>Título</h3><br><p>Aqui é feito a descrição</p>"));
```

Considerando este facto, qual seria seu equivalente? Como posso usar o `fromHtml()` para Android N+?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De facto [Html.fromHtml(String source)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) é agora considerado obsoleto. Isso, no entanto, não implica que não possa ser usado. Até porque não tem outra opção, caso queira que a app corra em versões anteriores à N.

O método que o substitui é [Html.fromHtml(String source, int flag)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int))<sup>(1)</sup>.

Ao parâmetro `flag` deve ser passada uma ou várias(separadas pelo operador *or* `|`) das constantes que a classe [Html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) declara.

Cada uma dessas "flags" indica como o *html* em `source` deve ser "interpretado" ao construir o [Spanned](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) retornado pela função.

Por exemplo, a constante `FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST` indica que texto dentro de elementos `<ul>` serão, por padrão, separados de outros textos por um *newline*.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> - Use a constante [Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY) para obter o comportamento anterior à versão N.</sub>

Comment: Muito bom Ramaral. +1. Não esperava outra resposta além dessa.

Comment: @ramaral, eu gostaria de substituir esta instrução obsoleta com esta que você mencionou, mas ela não aceita null como int flag. Só preciso que formate alguns links. Sabes dizer qual tag deveria usar?

Comment: @ReneFreak Use o a constante `Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY`